# jquery : Get html content between child and end of its parent

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div in the following structure

```
    <div id="article-content">
        <p>content of article</p>
        <h3 id="last-heading"></h3>
        <p>Content part 1 of last heading</p>
        <p>Content part 2 of last heading</p>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.in">Link</a>
        <div class="article-img"><img src="http://cdn4.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/Watches/Samsung/GearLive/Review/samsung-gear-live-watch-review-623-80.jpg"/></div>...

..
..
..
    </div>
```

I want the following html content in output:

```
 <p>Content part 1 of last heading</p>
        <p>Content part 2 of last heading</p>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.in">Link</a>
        <div class="article-img"><img src="http://cdn4.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/Watches/Samsung/GearLive/Review/samsung-gear-live-watch-review-623-80.jpg"/></div>...

..
..
..
```

ie. the html content after div with id last-heading until.
How to achieve this using jQuery
**Please note: the content is dynamic. Only reference we have is id :last-heading and we have to find complete html content from that id till end of its parent.**

Comment: You might wanna add a `class` attribute to the elements you want to select to avoid hard coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select the relevant element and use `outerHTML` property of it,

```
$('#article-content > p').slice(-2).map(function () {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join('')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/f9PXQ/)

Or if you want to select the paragraph elements particularly after one element, then use,

```
$('#last-heading ~ p').map(function () {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join('');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/f9PXQ/1/)

As per your new requirement, you can use `tilde followed by nothing` selector.

```
$('#last-heading ~').map(function () {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join('');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/f9PXQ/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the content is dynamic it can be anything a p, div, a etc. I think i should edit my question. Please suggest your answer accordingly

Comment: amazing, exactly what i want. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Can you also wrap that content selected into another div with id last-content. It would be great for me

Comment: @abhinsit Yes we can do that, Can you please ask that as a new question.. If we continue solving your issues here, it will be helpful for you but not for the future visitors.. :) I guess you got what i meant.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use map in jquery

```
$("#article-content").find("p:gt(0)").map(function () {
    return  return this.outerHTML;
}).get();
```

As your new requirement

```
$('#last-heading').nextUntil().map(function () {
    return  return this.outerHTML;
}).get();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MsGgP/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you could also use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/), as:

```
var allP = $('#last-heading').nextAll().map(function() {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join(); //comma separated
console.log(allP);
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwsBc/)